# How to mock a constructor object properties using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock a constructor 'EmailParams' in my test class.
Mocking is failing since the constructor EmailParams mocks as null.

Below is my test method

```
@Test
   public void getContactEmailsByFilterSuccessTest() throws Exception {

    String contactId = "752";
    String emailAddress = "test@gmail.com";
    String emailType = "EW";

    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    when(helper.isNumeric(any(String.class))).thenReturn(true);

    List<ContactXref> sourcedContacts = getContactXrefs();
    when(contactXrefServiceMock.getContactsForId(contactId)).thenReturn(sourcedContacts);

    EmailParams emailParams = new EmailParams("test@gmail.com", "EW", sourcedContacts.get(0).getContact().getContactId().toString());

    List<Email> emailsList = getEmailsList();
    when(emailServiceMock.getEmailByFilter(emailParams)).thenReturn(emailsList);

    ResponseEntity<List<Email>> response = contactControllerMock.getContactEmailsByFilter(request, contactId, emailAddress, emailType);
    Assert.assertEquals("getContactEmailsByFilterSuccessTest: Expected response code to be 200", "200", 
  response.getStatusCode().toString());   
 }
```

This is the method I am trying to mock. Test fails when its trying to mock the constructor

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{contactId}/" + UrlMapping.EMAILS, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Email>> getContactEmailsByFilter(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                            @PathVariable(name = RequestParams.CONTACTID) String contacId,
                                                            @RequestParam(required = false, name = RequestParams.EMAILADDRESS) String emailAddress,
                                                            @RequestParam(required = false, name = RequestParams.EMAILTYPE) String emailType)
                                                            throws Exception {


      ResponseEntity response = new ResponseEntity("Only numeric contactId is allowed", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

      List<Email> emailList;
      List<ContactXref> sourcedContacts;

      if (helper.isNumeric(contactId)) {

          sourcedContacts = contXrefService.getContactsForId(contactId);

          EmailParams params = new EmailParams(emailAddress, emailType, sourcedContacts.get(0).getContact().getContactId().toString());

          emailList = emailService.getEmailByFilter(params);
          if (emailList != null) {
               response = emailList.size() == 0 ? new ResponseEntity("No emails were found for the request", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) : new ResponseEntity(emailList, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
           } else {
              response = new ResponseEntity("Encountered exception in retrieving emails", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
          }
      }
       return response;
}
```

Here is my class which has the constructor.

```
public class EmailParams {

    String email;
    String emailType;
    String ptyId;

    public EmailParams() {
        super();
    }

    public EmailParams(String pEmail, String pEmailType, String pPtyId) {
        email = pEmail;
        emailType = pEmailType;
        ptyId = pPtyId;
    }
}
```

How to mock it properly? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `equals` method is not overridden in `EmailParams` class by default `Mockito` uses `Object.equals` to compare the `EmailParams` passed to `getEmailByFilter` method. In your case both object properties have same values but still they are different objects. So either override the `equals` method in `EmailParams` or
use `ArgumentMatchers.argThat`

```
 when(emailServiceMock.getEmailByFilter(ArgumentMatchers.argThat(p -> p.getPEmail().equals("test@gmail.com") && condition2 && condition3 )))
                  .thenReturn(emailsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

So `emailService` is expected to be invoked with `emailParams`. The `emailParams` is constructed using `emailAddress`, `emailType` and a `contactId`. If you look closely, you'll realize that `sourcedContacts` in your controller is the result of `contXrefService.getContactsForId(contactId)`.

Why is this a problem? Well, look at this line in your test:

`when(contactXrefServiceMock.getContactsForEcmId(contactId)).thenReturn(sourcedContacts)`

You're mocking `getContactsForEcmId` to return the `sourcedContacts`. Instead, you should be mocking `getContactsForId`.